# Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets was not found

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-rc2

I'm trying to "[Compiling source to native code using the ILCompiler](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/Documentation/how-to-build-and-run-ilcompiler-in-console-shell-prompt.md)".

I did:

1. dotnet new console
2. dotnet build
3. Changed the csproj to

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Import Project="$(MSBuildSDKsPath)\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" />
   <Import Project="$(IlcPath)\Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets" />
   ```

   4. `set IlcPath=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0`
   5. dotnet build

> ```
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.117.23532
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testproject\testproject.csproj(9,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testproject\testproject.csproj(9,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\testproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>     0 Warning(s)
>     1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.17
> ```

I used the x64 NAtive Tools Command PRompt for VS 2017

My Setup:

> dotnet --info .NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0-preview2-006080)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.0.0-preview2-006080 
>   Commit SHA-1 hash:  0a89053574
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.15063 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0-preview2-006080\
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.0-preview2-25309-07   Build    :
>   41f5fc94eedc889f086800c23f35bf14a8c75a9f

Whats about this Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets? It seems to be a kind of a special placeholder. How can I fix the above error?

Comment: Are you using the preview version of VS 2017?

Comment: No. Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.2 (26430.6)

Comment: I think you need the preview version for .net core 2.0 to work properly https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#windowscmd

Comment: I have installed that too. Obviously the filename of the setup is dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.0.0-preview1-005977.exe `dotnet --version` prints
2.0.0-preview2-006080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IlcPath` is mean to be set to the output of a build of CoreRT (`C:\path_to_your\corert\bin\Product\Windows_NT.x64.Debug\packaging\publish1`) and not your own app. You'll need to clone and build CoreRT for this to work.